# Apache 2.2 + Varnish not listening to 8080 port

Tags: apache-2.2, varnish

I'm running apache 2.2 with multiple VirtualHosts and varnish cache on Centos 6.6. The problem is I can't get this to work.

```
httpd.conf:
Listen 8080
NameVirtualHost *:8080
<VirtualHost *:8080>
ServerName example.com
ServerAlias www.example.com
DocumentRoot /home/example/public_html
```

Varnish is set to run on 80 port and `DAEMON_OPTS="-a :80`

```
default.vcl:
backend default {
.host = "127.0.0.1";
.port = "8080";}
```

Content of `/etc/hosts`

```
127.0.0.1 localhost
2a01:xxx:190:xxx8::2
5.0.100.000
```

Whenever I try to reach my virtualhost I see `/var/www/html` content.

What should I do?

Comment: Where ate you trying to access the system from itself or another system ?

Comment: From another system.

Comment: I have noticed error message varnishd[10982]: Child start failed: could not open sockets. If I start varnish first its ok, but when I try to start httpd Address already in use: make_sock: could not bind to address xxxxxxxx:80

Answer (score 0):

**Edit:** I re-read the question.

Grep your `httpd.conf` for `Listen` and `Include` directives. If you don't find any extra `Listen` directives in the `httpd.conf`, repeat the process on any files or directories referenced by `Include` directives.

Something is telling Apache to continue listening on port 80, you just need to find which file/line is doing it.

**Original:**

your apache config for a `Listen` directive - it's probably trying to listen on port 80 still.

On Debian and probably Ubuntu systems this would be in `/etc/apache2/ports.conf`

Change the `Listen 80` to `Listen 8080`

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved! Seems there was more Listen params in ssl.conf, commented out all except Listen 443, everything seems to be working fine now.